# multidimensional arrays in php with parse error

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
<?php
array $food= array('healthy'=>
array('Salad','Vege',Pasta'),
'unhealthy'=>   
array('pizza','icecream'));
echo $food['unhealthy'][1];
?>
```

i am writing this code but getting this error on browser:

> error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$food' (T_VARIABLE),
>   expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\foreach.php on line 2

Comment: See the manual how to define a basic array: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

Remove **array** at the starting and also there is missing **single quote** before **Pasta**.

Try this

```
<?php

    $food = array(
              'healthy'=> array('Salad', 'Vege', 'Pasta'),
              'unhealthy'=> array('pizza', 'icecream')
            );

    echo $food['unhealthy'][1];

?>
```